# Where should concatenation take place in the order of operations?

Tags: notation, recreational-mathematics

Concatenation being the joining of two integers by their numerals, or, more plainly, just smooshing the numbers together (denoted $a \ || \ b$ .) Examples: $5 \ || \ 2 = 52$, and $20 \ || \ 17 = 2017$.

My question is where do you think concatenation should go in the order of operations? **And why?**

Or, how would you evaluate $5 \times 1 \ || \ 2 + 4$ ? **And why?**

1. $5 \times 1 \ || \ 2 + 4 = (5 \times 1) \ || \ 2 + 4 = 5 \ || \ 2 + 4= 52 + 4 = 56$,
2. $5 \times 1 \ || \ 2 + 4 = 5 \times (1 \ || \ 2) + 4 = 5 \times 12 + 4= 60 + 4 = 64$.

**Edit:** I intend on using concatenation in expressions with exponentiation, multiplication/division, and addition/subtraction. No parenthesis, that would be too obvious, since concatenation would probably *have* to come after parenthesis in the order of operations.

Comment: What kinds of expressions do you want to write down with this symbol? That will determine the most useful answer to your question.

Comment: pick one and stick to it.  its not standard either way.

Comment: Cryptographers frequently use concatenation. You might see if there's a standard they use, or ask your question on the Crypto SE. Similarly you could check programming languages (if any) that have the operand. That's complicated somewhat by the fact that "+" is often overloaded to mean concatenation. The "+" overload-as-concatenation is somewhat consistent with the answer that references "Parker" in that it has less precedence than multiplication.

Comment: I would just use parentheses to spare your readers headaches. No real reason to try to define an order of operations here.  Unless you are designing a programming language or something - then I would look into what the standards are in languages that use a similar syntax.

Comment: I would think of conatenation as a function from $\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$ and and so, the elements to be concatenated would happen before multiplication.

Comment: Well, if you think about it, concatenation can be defined using preexisting operations. If $AB$ and $CD$ are two digit numbers with digits $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, for example, then
$$AB||CD=A*10^3+B*10^2+C*10^1+D*10^0$$

Answer (score 5):

Consider that whenever you write a numeral with more than one digit, that's concatenation, denoted by the empty string, and it always has higher precedence than arithmetic operators.  $12+12$ is $24$, not $132$, and $12 \times 12$ is $144$, not $122$.  So one argument is that if you're going to give concatenation an alternate symbol, the simplest choice is to keep the precedence the same.

(This is a bit more complicated when multiplication is also denoted by the empty string, in which case for example $3(1+2)$ means $9$, not $33$, and $10x$ means ten times $x$, not $10^{2+\lceil \log_{10}{x} \rceil}+x$.  The ambiguity is resolved by making the empty string denote concatenation when both operands are digit strings and multiplication otherwise.  But that's not a universal convention, think about those puzzles where you're supposed to solve for the unknown digits, like $10x + y0x = x10$.)

On the other hand it may be more aesthetic to associate precedence with the appearance of the glyph.  The double vertical bar I think creates a sense of wide spacing, so it looks like it should be a low precedence operator.

perl has a separate operator for concatenation (.) and it is given a low precedence.  Personally I prefer $\cdot$ (\$\cdot\$) to the double vertical bar, and I would prefer it to have a high precedence.  But there isn't really one right way to do it.  I think it's possible to walk a narrow path and avoid either overusing parentheses or tediously explaining your usage: just use it enough times in a context where there is only one sensible interpretation of the precedence, and an attentive reader can figure it out.

Comment: That's an interesting point, I guess I never really saw that all multi-digit numbers are the concatenation of their digits, being concatenated by the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

In the video [The 10958 Problem by Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pasyRUj7UwM), Parker uses concatenations to solve the problem. As he does this, he treats concatinations as after multiplication and division, but before addition and subtraction. So I believe the Order of Operations would be PEMDCAS.

However, concatenations are not really well used, so it really wouldn't go into the order of operations properly :D

Comment: You know what's funny? My question arose from code based off that video series and the Four Fours videos! I guess I forgot that Parker had used it in that order.

Comment: Ha Really? Well, that's funny! :D

Answer (score -1):

It is quite rare to use concatenation in the same expression with multiplication or addition.  I would just shoot anybody who wrote $5 \times 1||2+4$ and if they survived offer them a lifetime supply of parentheses.  My real answer is that there is no convention because concatenation is a recreational operation while addition and multiplication are real mathematical operations.   Anything you do with concatenation is dependent on the base you are operating in, and real math doesn't do that.

I enjoy puzzles that involve the digits of numbers, but in a sense that is not mathematics.

Comment: Downvoted because that is way too broad and judgemental.  Isn't the point just that there isn't a standard convention for concatenation because the base is arbitrary?  $2$ is the least arbitrary, and there's no standard for that, so I suspect there are other reasons.

Comment: @DanBrumleve:   Thank you for giving your reasons for the downvote.  I disagree, but I think the different views will help OP.

Comment: Okay, but at what level of irony do your views make any sense?  It's not fake math just because it has two strings written side by side.  Repunit primes aren't real mathematics, but what about Mersenne ones?

Comment: @DanBrumleve:  I would say Mersenne ones are real.  Depending on what base the number is represented in takes it out of real for me.  I enjoy problems that depend on the representation, but recognize that they are in a different category.  Often divisibility makes a bridge between them.

Comment: So spare OP the firing squad for two bars we can agree to blame on a typesetting error.  Concatenation is everywhere in math if you look for it, right?

Comment: @DanBrumleve Personally the firing squad might be overkill, but I agree with Mr. Millikan that a life time supply of parentheses is in order. In math and science in general being understood is an essential goal. Being intentionally obtuse is annoying, wastes time and just doesn't make sense. Either define the precedence order at the beginning of your paper/problem/quiz/thingamajig or use parentheses. I've always disliked problems where the goal is to abuse notation to make and easy thing hard. That's psychology not math.